# One object isn't rendering a shadow in Cycles

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view, shadows

I haven't encountered this issue before, so I apologize if this is a simple fix... but I'm trying to work on a small interior scene, and for some reason, I can get the shadow of a table to show up in the 3D viewport, but the same shadow doesn't show up in the actual render.

Some screenshots:

There's no shadow in the bottom right of the image.
[image: No shadow (near bottom-right)]

If I hit Tab to enter edit mode, the shadow reappears.
[image: If I hit Tab to enter edit mode, the shadow appears again.]

But then even with the shadow visible, when I render the image, the shadow is gone again.
[image: The shadow disappeared again.]

Can someone poke around [my .blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fvDa2EnWVyVa-S5tvwaJVk9HrtlIkQwU/view?usp=sharing) and see if anything is strange? Again, I've never encountered this issue before, so I'm not sure what could be the cause...

Thanks! :)

Comment: Hello, your file is 542 Mb large, please post a minimal working example without the textures if you want us to take a look. Also please make sure "Shadow" is not disabled for this particular model in the properties  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Erpr9.png

Comment: Hello, I updated the link... It's still 160mb though.. I don't know how to make it any smaller. :(

Comment: next time delete all objects not necessary and include the textures to the blend file (otherwise the scene is all violet)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you just need to select the table and check the "shadow" checkbox under "object properties"

[image]