# Shadow not showing in Renderer

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, blender-internal-render-engine, shadows, shadowcatcher

I have a problem where the shadow is not showing up during the rendering scene, even though the shadow shows up on the viewport.

On viewport[image]
On Rendering[image]
I don't know why this happens, any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Here is the blender file as well https://github.com/NindyBun/Concentrated_Solar_Power_0.1.0/blob/master/csp_heater.blend

Comment: First, see if this answers your question - https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/207150/110840

if you're rendering transparent you may need to add a shadowcatcher plane

Comment: please provide blend file

Answer (score 1):

I have taken a look at your file. The transparent plane on which your shadow is casted has a setting for it to show or no to show shadows, and in which scenario.

Select that plane, go to the object settings on the right side and find this section:
[image]

In your case, only 'show in viewports' was ticked. You also need to tick the box that says 'show in renders' and your render will look the way you imagined it.

Good luck!